# ios: Change the resolution when capturing an image with OpenCV using cvSetCaptureProperty

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, opencv, camera

I am working on an Iphone application. I am using OpenCV to take a picture with the camera and use it as UIImage.

To take the picture first I declare the cvCapture

```
CvCapture * capture = cvCaptureFromCam(1200) //(1200 is to use the CV_CAP_AVFOUNDATION  from the AVFoundation framework)
```

Then I use `cvQueryFrame(capture)` to get the image.

Everything works correctly.

Now the image resolution I get is 480X360. i want to make the image bigger. After researches and some test on a desktop application I found out we can use this to set the capture resolution:

```
cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280);
cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 720);
```

However this was not working the image size is not changing.

Directly after calling `cvSetCaptureProperty` I used the `cvGetCaptureProperty` to read the properties, to make sure they are changing. But they where not changing (I'm still getting them as 480X360). It is like `cvSetCaptureProperty` is not setting the properties correctly.

On a desktop application that uses open CV those methods work fine and the resolution is changed correctly. I am testing on an Iphone 4s btw.

Any idea why setting the frame height and width is not working?

Thanks a lot for any help

Comment: Does Your imaging device support 1280 X 720?? ...check that first..

Comment: @Youssef Have you fond the solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: @Remizorrr sorry I was not able to find a solution. I ended up using the built in ios camera framework which allows you to set the resolution.

Comment: @Youssef I am on the same way now, looking for a fast way to convert CVPixelBufferRef to IplImage. Thank you for your reply.